# Bash script: save stream from Serial Port (/dev/ttyUSB0) to file until a specific input (e.g. eof) appears

Tags: bash, serial-port, eof, cat

I need a bash script to read the data stream from a Serial Port (RS232 to USB adapter - Port: /dev/ttyUSB0). The data should be stored line by line in a file until a specific input (for example "eof") appears. I can give any external input to the Serial Port.
Till now I use cat to read the data, which works fine.

```
cat /dev/ttyUSB0 -> file.txt
```

The problem is, that I need to finish the command myself by entering cntr+C, but I don't know exactly when the data stream ends and the ttyUSB0 file does not gerenate an EOF. I tried to implement this myself, but did not find a convenient solution.
The following command works, but I don't know how to use it for my problem ("world" will create a "command not found" error):

```
#!/bin/bash
cat > file.txt << EOF
hello
EOF
world
```

The following code works for my problem, but it takes too much time (the data stream consists of ~2 million lines):

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line; do
     if [ "$line" != "EOF" ]; then
          echo "$line" >> file.txt
     else
          break
     fi
done < /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Has anyone a convenient possibility for my problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `awk(1)`:

```
awk `
/EOF/ {exit;} 
 {print;}` < /dev/ttyUSB0 > file.txt
```

This stops when it sees the line `EOF` and prints everything else to `file.txt`